# Hexadecimal manipulation woes. Cannot reach expected value

Tags: java, hex, mean

I am supposed to merge the values of source and background arrays to get the value in expected (the answer array).

```
    int[][] source =     { { 0, 0x44, 0x300, 0x660000 } };
    int[][] background = { { 2, 4,    0x600, 2 } };
    int[][] expected =   { { 1, 0x24, 0x400 , 0x330001 } };
```

I noticed the problem is just asking for the mean of the two sets of numbers for all the cases except for the third (meaning I've passed all the tests except for the 0x300/0x600 one). The third case, is strange, I think. I represented the two hexadecimals in binary as such:

```
    0011 0000 0000 (+)
    0110 0000 0000 I get:
    1001 0000 0000.
```

The expected is 0x400, 1024 in base 10, 100 0000 0000 in base 2. I don't see how I can get to that solution.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? Is it possible that the question is just wrong? You're normally told *how* you're meant to get to certain values, rather than having to guess...

Comment: Yes, this is an assignment. I've already emailed a TA about how this might be a broken question. I was told to merge, but I inferred "take the mean" from that. I was thinking perhaps I overlooked some detail I didn't know

Comment: So the mean of those two would be 0x480 which might look quite similar to 0x400, depending on the font. That might be another indicator for the question being wrong (actually it might be a reason).

Comment: Well, I downloaded the problems off of a repository. I never had to change or read from the grading test class at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term `background` makes me think, it has to do with image/pixel manipulation. In that context each pixel contains the three components for red, green and blue. If each component is one byte wide (values from 0 to 255), then a 32 bit integer can hold all three components. And "take the mean" must be done **on each component separatly** since you don't want the "green" channel to affect the "blue" channel.

Let's assume the representation 0x00rrggbb.

```
src: 0x00660000 -> 0x00, 0x66, 0x00, 0x00
bac: 0x00000002 -> 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02
adding components: 0x00, 0x66, 0x00, 0x0x
dividing comp    : 0x00, 0x33, 0x00, 0x01
exp:                 OK    OK    OK    OK
```

Do the same with 0x0300, 0x0600 and you will see, that the division of "green" would affect "blue" if not rounded properly. Doing the math by components solved this.